# Meteor observeChanges() called twice when it should be called once

Tags: javascript, meteor

The newest meteor's observeChanges cursor method appears to be being called twice, I'm unsure why.

In a client only file, theres the following code:

```
Meteor.startup(function () {
//TODO BROKEN
    CodeFiles.find({_id: Session.get('currentFile')}).observeChanges({
        changed: function(id, fields) {
            console.log("Codefile changed");
            console.log(fields);
        }
    });
});
```

Which results in the following in my browser,

```
Codefile changed client.js:165
Object {edits: Object}
 client.js:166
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/sockjs/991/bm7f2oa8/xhr_send". sockjs-0.3.4.js:821
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/sockjs/991/bm7f2oa8/xhr". sockjs-0.3.4.js:821
Codefile changed client.js:165
Object {}
```

As you can see, the observeChanges method is called twice, once with the correct edit object, correct data included. A second time with a blank object. This isn't a huge problem, as I can check for an empty object and compensate, but I'd rather fix the underlying problem.

Full code open-source and viewable here: 
[Github commit link](https://github.com/joeljfischer/meteor-collabmirror/tree/c07814863e19cdd252f9410ccc15a73b34656e18)

Note the specific commit number if you run the code to see the issue in the javascript console. In later commits I'm just doing an undefined check, but I would like the see the root issue resolved, as sending over useless data is an issue.

Comment: Oops!  This is probably a bug.  I'll take a look at fixing it on devel tomorrow.  :)

Comment: It is fixed on devel now!

Comment: Thanks so much, I'm not developing my app based on the devel branch, but I'll look for the fix in a future point release. Maybe near term? Anyways, just glad I was able to help you guys out!

Comment: I still have that issue with this code: https://gist.github.com/daslicht/e872c04bcb7feee81f33, Meteor 1.2.0.2: